# print pos receipt in tow printer in web application

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, printing

I'm using a web application and the frontend is HTML, CSS, js, jquery, vuejs2 etc.
I need to print to two printers.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>item 1 * 150 $</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 5 * 160 $</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 3 * 70 $</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 9 * 80 $</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>footer here</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I want to print the page using `ctrl + p` it will print in the first printer only.  How can I print to two different printers?
my os is windows 10
and my browser is chrome and sometimes edge ..

Comment: Assuming you're trying to print through a web browser, you can't print to multiple devices from a single print request. You will need to print twice, manually changing the target printer device in the dialog each time.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is correct you can't do this natively.  If this is on Windows, you could use a 3rd party tool to facilitate or have the file automatically written to a file on the file system, monitor that folder, and then send the print-ready output to both printers via a copy \\localhost\printershare or similar.  This assumes that you have control over the install and usage of the system and that the printers are similar.  And in this case it's on Windows, to sure on Mac or other OSs.  I've done this before, can provide more detail if need.

Comment: Douglas Anderson thanks a lot im using it on windows can you provide me any 3rd party tool to do that .. thanks .

Comment: check my answer hope the links would help.

Comment: And try searching online for answers so like the problem is not in the code but in the network you should be able to add two printers and make them work together.
If the answer was helpful please accept it as helpful as in trick it. Thanks.

Comment: so was my answer helpful if so could you like please tick it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically you can't be able to use two printers at once cause the os will only send the data to one printer and might even printer 2 pages in the same printer.

But why really do you want to print with 2 printers.
If there is a specific reason for why you want to do this could you like please mention it.

But check this link as well for more info on using a third party website.

https://itstillworks.com/13331277/how-to-print-on-two-printers-at-a-time

https://bizfluent.com/info-7905752-can-two-printers-one-computer.html

https://www.foldermill.com/solutions/automatically-print-documents-on-many-printers

Hope one of these links are useful